# Is there a way to copy and paste on the Java side while dynamcly changing the content of the clipboard?

Tags: java

I am trying to copy and paste from Excel into our own application into several fields.
For this i am reading out the clipboard and create an array which is equal to the fields beeing copied from excel.

The look of the application is somehow equal to excel, you can go into the next column with tab, and into the next row with enter. The following code should read the clipboard content and Paste the Strings immediatly. to do this i am using the Key Robot in combination with the setting of the clipboard. Now i am running into the following problem. I set the new Clipboard content in the loop for every cell in the Excel sheet. i am getting the single value for each cell with
getClipboardContents, but the Robot pressing ctrl + v does still copy the whole area beeing copied in Excel. Is there a way to copy and paste on the Java side while dynamcly changing the content of the clipboard?

```
private String getClipboardContents() {
    String result = "";
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    // odd: the Object param of getContents is not currently used
    Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
    boolean hasTransferableText = (contents != null) && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    if (hasTransferableText) {
        try {
            result = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
            // highly unlikely since we are using a standard DataFlavor
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            npe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private String[][] generateExcelArray() {
    String clipboard = getClipboardContents();
    String[] rows = clipboard.split("\n");
    String[][] table = new String[rows.length][rows[0].split("\t").length];
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; ++i) {
        String[] row = rows[i].split("\t");
        int _a = 0;
        if (row.length != table[i].length) 
            _a = table[i].length - row.length;
        for (int j = 0; j+_a < table[i].length; ++j) {
            String cell = row[j];
            table[i][j+_a] = cell;
        }
    }
    return table;
}

private void fillFields() throws AWTException {
    String[][] excelTable = generateExcelArray();
    Robot keySender = new Robot();
    String bufferCopy = getClipboardContents();
    for (int i = 0; i < excelTable.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < excelTable[i].length; ++j) {
            setClipboard(excelTable[i][j]);
            keySender.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            keySender.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            keySender.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            keySender.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            keySender.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            keySender.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        }
        keySender.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        keySender.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
    setClipboard(bufferCopy);
}

private void setClipboard(String input) {
    StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(input);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
    System.out.println(getClipboardContents());
}
```

Comment: Have a look into buffer classes in `nio` package. Possible helpful methods could be `flip` and `compact`.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tests i found out, that the it does recognize the change internally, but windows doesn´t.
Setting up the paste procedure into Threads with some delays of 5 ms was enough for windows to execute the clipboardchanges.

```
final String[][] excelTable = generateExcelArray();
    final Robot keySender = new Robot();
    final String bufferCopy = getClipboardContents();
    final int delay = 5;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < excelTable.length; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < excelTable[i].length; ++j) {
                    setClipboard(excelTable[i][j] == null ? "":excelTable[i][j]);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(delay);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    keySender.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                    keySender.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                    keySender.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                    keySender.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(delay);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    keySender.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    keySender.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                keySender.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                keySender.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setClipboard(bufferCopy);
        }
    }).start();
```